# How to use foreach loop inside Invoke-Command in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

In the below code I was using `$scripts` variable to iterate through a `foreach` loop inside the `Invoke-Command` statement. But `$script` values are not replacing properly and outcome seems to be single string as "count.sql size.sql". The `foreach` loop is executing properly if defined outside the `Invoke-Command` loop.

Is there any particular way to define `foreach` loop inside `Invoke-Command`?

```
$scripts = @("count.sql", "size.sql")
$user = ""
$Password = ""
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $SecurePassword

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        Param($server, $InputFile, $scripts, $url)

        foreach ($script in $scripts) {
            echo "$script"
    } -ArgumentList "$server,"$scripts","$url"
}
```

Comment: this script doesnt look complete. You dont seem to be calling the varables on the server correctly

Comment: since your edit it looks like your argument list is wrong. You are declaring all your varables as string by using the " around them. Change argument list to 
-ArgumentList $server, $scripts, $url

Also your not declaring all the arugments in order....Server, Inputfile, Scripts, URL.  Currently $Scripts is = to $inputfile

Comment: The `-argumentList` parameter also looks to be incorrectly placed. It's currently inside the script block.

Comment: seems like issue is with the double quotes in ArgumentList.., It worked fine after removing the qoutes. Thanks for the response :) Can we define new variables inside the invoke-command script block? If I define then it was showing error as param() is not recognized. How can I define new variable inside the invoke-command block?

Comment: It's clearly not possible that the code you posted could ever have run successfully. the nested `foreach` loop is missing a closing curly bracket, and the first argument to the `-ArgumentList` parameter is missing a closing double quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the syntax errors in your code are just typos in your question and are not present in your actual code.

The problem you describe has nothing to do with the nested `foreach` loop. It's caused by the double quotes you put around the arguments you pass to the invoked scriptblock. Putting an array in double quotes mangles the array into a string with the string representations of the values from the array separated by the [output field separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#ofs) defined in the automatic variable `$OFS` (by default a space). To avoid this behavior don't put variables in double quotes when there is no need to do so.

Change the `Invoke-Command` statement to something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Param($server, $scripts, $url)
    ...
} -ArgumentList $server, $scripts, $url
```

and the problem will disappear.

Alternatively you could use the variables from outside the scriptblock via the `using` [scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-3.0):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    foreach ($script in $using:scripts) {
        echo "$script"
    }
}
```